# Programmatically access the <compilation /> section of a web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, configuration

Is there any way to access the `<compilation />` tag in a web.config file?

I want to check if the "*debug*" attribute is set to "*true*" in the file, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've tried using the `WebConfigurationManager`, but that doesn't seem to allow me to get to the `<compilation />` section.

**Update:**

I know I could easily just load the file like an XML Document and use XPath, but I was hoping there was already something in the framework that would do this for me. It seems like there would be something since there are already ways to get App Settings and Connection Strings.

I've also tried using the `WebConfigurationManager.GetSection()` method in a few ways:

```
WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("compilation")// Name of the tag in the file
WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("CompilationSection") // Name of the class that I'd expect would be returned by this method
WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web") // Parent tag of the 'compilation' tag
```

All of the above methods return `null`. I'm assuming there is a way to get to this configuration section since there is a class that already exists ('`CompilationSection`'), I just can't figure out how to get it.

Comment: Do you add your section to `configSections`? something like: `<configSections> <section name="compilation" type="xxx" /> ... </configSections>`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

...

```
  CompilationSection configSection =
          (CompilationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "system.web/compilation" );
```

You can then check the `configSection.Debug` property.

**TIP:** if you need to know how to get a value from a config file, check the machine.config file in your `\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\<version>\CONFIG` folder. In there you can see how all the configuration section handlers are defined. Once you know the name of the config handler (in this case, CompilationSection), you can look it up in the .Net docs.

Answer (score 24):

The easy way to check if you're running in debug mode is to use the [HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled.aspx) property. It gets its answer from the compilation element's debug attribute which is the same thing you're trying to do.

Comment: This is the best answer for when you have an `HttpContext` instance (i.e. when you're handling a request in a controller), but if you need to do it in another place within the application, like the `Global.asax` code, then @MikeScott's answer is what you'll need.

Answer (score 3):

After all, you can always load up the `Web.config` file into an `XmlDocument` and use an `XPath` query to find out!

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));     
doc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/system.web/compilation/@debug");
```

However, I suggest you use the `Configuration.GetSection` method for solution.

```
CompilationSection section = 
    Configuration.GetSection("system.web/compilation") as CompilationSection;
bool debug = section != null && section.Debug;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always check debug option on the compiler level by enclosing your code with

```
#if (DEBUG)

#endif
```

in case that was the idea...

Comment: This is not the web.config flag as it can be changed during runtime. As you wrote this is compile time only and therefore depends on weather one does a DEBUG or RELEASE build (compilation). That's not what was asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just load the file up as a regular XML File and use XPath to get the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ConfigurationManager.GetSection method.