# Getting the .NET framework setting for <compilation debug="true">

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

In my web.config I have the standard element;

```
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#">
```

I know I could use [Conditional("DEBUG")] on methods, or use some pre-compiler if statement like #if DEBUG, but what I am looking for is the built-in .NET framework setting that lets me know if the setting for debug in the compilation section.

I've seen it done before but can't find it or remember it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically access the <compilation /> section of a web.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401306/programmatically-access-the-compilation-section-of-a-web-config)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled (posted by Jason Diamond) was what I was looking for.

Thanks for your help Marc!

Comment: You might want to close the question, then. And maybe chuck Jason a +1 ;-p

Comment: How do I close a question? (Sorry - bit of a noob)