# How to make Microsoft Bundle output JavaScript not HTML script tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am building a ASP.NET MVC4 based jQuery plug-in and I would like to use the standard [Microsoft Bundler](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bundle%20Transformer%201.7.23).

Now normally when I use the bundler the final usage is this:

```
@Scripts.Render(BundleConfig.jsBundleFile)
```

With a output like this in debug:

```
<script src="/Scripts/..."></script>
<script src="/Scripts/..."></script>
<script src="/Scripts/..."></script>
<script src="/Scripts/..."></script>
<script src="/Scripts/..."></script>
<script src="/Scripts/..."></script>
```

And a single tag to the minified and combined file in the official release.

However, because we are building a jQuery plug-in I want to use the minifier to insert the actual JavaScript from the various files i.e. in DEBUG, when I have `Object1` defined in one file and `Object2` defined in another then I get this:

```
/* Content from file #1 */
var Object1 = function() { /* Un-minified content of Object1 */ };
/* Content from file #2 */
var Object2 = function() { /* Un-minified content of Object2 */ };
```

and in the release I would get the minified content.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scripts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I saw that the bundler, by default can't do that. But I am wondering is there an extension that can do this or another minifing library that can? Though I'd prefer to stay with the Microsoft Bundler.

In my own research on how to extend the System.Web.Optimizer I found the [CodePlex](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#readme.markdown) project of `System.Web.Optimization`, where it is said it's not open source as of yet, with makes the extending kinda difficult to anyone not really working on it.

**EDIT :**  So knowing that I can't really expand the System.Web.Optimizer I went with a compromise solution and this is what I ended up using.

In the Controller:

```
public JavaScriptResult jQueryComponent()
{
    JavaScriptResult ret = new JavaScriptResult();
    ClientSettings Model = new ClientSettings();

#if DEBUG
    List<string> jsFiles = App_Start.BundleConfig.Main.FilesToBeBundledJS;
    StringBuilder bundleBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string file in jsFiles)
    {
        bundleBuilder.Append(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(file)));
    }

    ViewBag.bundledJS = bundleBuilder.ToString();
#else
    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("http://localhost");

    int port = Request.Url.Port;
    if (port != -1) {
        urlBuilder.Append(':');
        urlBuilder.Append(port);
    }

    urlBuilder.Append(Scripts.Url(App_Start.BundleConfig.Main.jsBundleFile));

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    byte[] raw = wc.DownloadData(urlBuilder.ToString());
    string bundledJS = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);

    ViewBag.bundledJS = bundledJS;
#endif

    ret.Script = RenderRazorViewToString("~/Views/Main/jQueryComponent.cshtml", Model);

    return ret;
}

private string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

And in the View (*jQueryComponent.cshtml*):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

if (typeof jQuery != 'function') {
    throw "This is a jQuery plugin i.e. jQuery needs to be defined first";
}

(function ($) {

    //Adds the bundled JS into the plug-in
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.bundledJS)

    $.fn.jsPlugIn = function() {
    /*
        Creates a new instance of [MainObject] with is defined in the bundle.
    */    
        //uses the bundled JS
        var Main = new MainObject();
        Main.doSomething();

        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Any ideas how to improve this are welcome alongside the proper extention to the bundler.
 
Although works, this is far from ideal and I am well aware of this.
Please do not criticise *this approach* unless you have an alternative.

Comment: have you tried the Bundling features built in to the Visual studio Web Essentials plugin?  This bundler bundles at compile time instead of runtime, which seems to suit your needs. http://vswebessentials.com/features/general

Comment: @Andrew I am not really a big fan of plug-ins (they are kinda hard to push within the company, unless they are MS ones), but from a quick glanse it seams to me that this creates a separate minified file for the project, with I can include into my project. What I'd prefer is a solution like in the Web.Optimizer were I can update the files (on a deployed project) and have them combine into a single JS file for the client i.e. all the minification is done on runtime and not in the project deployment.

Comment: Why do you need all the .js in a simple javascript for developing a jquery plugin? I've developed many of them, and I can't see the reason. Perhaps instead of trying to do this you must change your way of facing this problem. If I understand why you think you need this, hopefully I'll be able to show you good alternatives. I've never needed it, and have several plugins in production.

Comment: It's not a component like a new scrollbar or anything like that. The customer is paying for the data that the plugin is showing and not the plugin itself. So the JS and ASP.NET are really linked. We need to be able to return nothing if the customer leaves us. The other big reason is that the code is OOP style JS, for example its not unusual for me to have 10 objects in 10 files for one project. This is why I can't use the minifiers own output. I need to incapsulate the code in the jQuery plugin. I also do not want to work with one file which has 10k+ lines.

Comment: @JotaBe I am not really looking for an alternative JS approache (see previous comment as to why) only a way to get the minified JS as a string in C#.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do what the BundleHandler does: Get a [bundle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundle.aspx) based on the virtual path (same one you would use for
    `@Script.Render`), [generate the response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundle.generatebundleresponse.aspx) and write the [contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundleresponse.content.aspx).

```
@{
    var context = new BundleContext(this.Context, BundleTable.Bundles, string.Empty);
    var bundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/VIRTUALPATH");
    var response = bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(context);
    var content = response.Content;

    this.WriteLiteral(content);
}
```

Or in short:

```
@Html.Raw(BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/VIRTUALPATH").GenerateBundleResponse(new BundleContext(this.Context, BundleTable.Bundles, string.Empty)).Content)
```

EDIT: To get unminified content in debug, we can do what [Scripts does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scripts.renderformat.aspx): Get the bundle again, but instead of generating the response, we [iterate its files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundle.enumeratefiles.aspx) and write their contents ([delimited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundle.concatenationtoken.aspx)).

```
@{
    var context = new BundleContext(this.Context, BundleTable.Bundles, string.Empty);
    var bundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/VIRTUALPATH");

    if (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations)
    {
        var response = bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(context);
        var content = response.Content;

        this.WriteLiteral(content);
    }
    else
    {
        var files = bundle.EnumerateFiles(context);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var stream = file.VirtualFile.Open();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                this.Output.Write("{0}{1}", reader.ReadToEnd(), bundle.ConcatenationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need (when you print the `content` through `@Html.Raw()` if you use `this.Write(content);` you get junk) it seams to print out only minified content. Do you know of a way how to get the unminified content in DEBUG?

Comment: Correct about the junk (HTML encoding), edited. Also added DEBUG handling.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to create your own class for doing this, and an stable minifier.

As to the minifier you can use one of these:

- [YUI compressor (used by Yahoo)](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)
- [Microsoft AJAX Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) (be aware that WebGrease already includes Ajax Minifier and you can get a conflict if you add both NuGet packages)

Your custom class should:

- be static
- contain a `List<string>` to hold the files in each bundle
- conatin a dictionary, to hold the bundle names and its files: `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` with a bundle name `string`, and a list of file names `List<string>`.

To create the non-minified version you simply need to read all the files into a string with any of the classes available for this (for ezample `StringBuilder`, `StringWriter`, `StreamReader`, `File`). If you need to mimic the wildcard names in the bundler, use `Directory`, and perhaps `Regex` classes.

The result of the reading should be stored in an static dictionary, which holds the bundle name and the bundle content (for caching, and avoiding reading the same files over and over).

An finally, you need to minify it.

You can toggle the minificacion depending on two different things:

- the definition of debug in the c# code `#ifdef DEBUG` ... `#endif` which depends on the solution configuration chosen in the configuration manager: debug/release
- [the compilation mode defined in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401306/programmatically-access-the-compilation-section-of-a-web-config)

Minifying with YUI compressor:

```
  JavaScriptCompressor jsCompressor = new JavaScriptCompressor();
  jsCompressor.ObfuscateJavascript = true; // Optional
  string minified = jsCompressor.Compress(originalScript);
```

Minifying with MS Ajax Minifier:

```
  Minifier min = new Minifier();
  string minified = min.MinifyJavaScript(originalScript);
```

You should also store the minified versions in an static dictionary to also cache them.

This is a basic working sample:

```
public class MyMinifier
{
    protected static Dictionary<string,List<string>> VirtualPathsInBundle
        = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    protected static Dictionary<string, string> OriginalJavascriptInBundle
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected static Dictionary<string, string> MinifiedJavascriptInBundle
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static void AddBundle(string bundleName, params string[] virtualPaths)
    {
        VirtualPathsInBundle.Add(bundleName, virtualPaths.ToList());
    }

    public static string GetOriginalJavaScript(string bundleName)
    {
        if (!OriginalJavascriptInBundle.ContainsKey(bundleName))
        {
            var physicalFilePaths = VirtualPathsInBundle[bundleName]
                .Select(vp => HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(vp));
            // If you use wildcards, expand them here...
            StringBuilder scripts = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var path in physicalFilePaths)
            {
                scripts.AppendFormat("// path: {0}", path);
                scripts.AppendLine();
                scripts.Append(File.ReadAllText(path));
            }
            OriginalJavascriptInBundle.Add(bundleName, scripts.ToString());
        }
        return OriginalJavascriptInBundle[bundleName];
    }

    public static string GetMinifiedJavaScript(string bundleName)
    {
        if (!MinifiedJavascriptInBundle.ContainsKey(bundleName))
        {
            Minifier minifier = new Minifier();
            MinifiedJavascriptInBundle[bundleName]
                = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(GetOriginalJavaScript(bundleName));
        }
        return MinifiedJavascriptInBundle[bundleName];
    }
}
```